# Plotting bar charts by each two rows

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have something like this

```
 id_1 1000
 id_2 200
 id_3  100
 id_4  50
```

Now since this is in a dataframe I can do df.plot(kind='bar') 
However this not what I really want I want something like seperate bar charts for each two consecutive id's.
Would it be better to pivot the dataframe and then plot from there?
Or is there a neat loop I can use. I'm quite bad at using matplotlib.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? Maybe provide a sketch of what you have in mind? The [bar chart demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) has grouped bars.

Comment: Please, clarify, what exactly are input data (not sure, if `id_1` means a string or some symbolic value) and what bar  charts you want to have plotted (e.g. show nameo of each chart with specified x-values and y-values).

Comment: Jan your answer gets exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import what is needed:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Create the data to plot:

```
>>> data = [10, 12, 8, 44, 34, 18]
>>> idx = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
>>> ser = pd.Series(data, index=idx)
>>> ser
a    10
b    12
c     8
d    44
e    34
f    18
dtype: int64
```

Finally create subseries and plot them

```
>>> # how many bar charts we expect
>>> numofcharts = len(ser) / 2

>>> # prepare axes for subplots (1 row, numofcharts columns one per bar chart)
>>> fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, numofcharts)

>>> for graphi in range(numofcharts):
>>>     starti = 2*graphi
>>>     # create subseries one for each subchart
>>>     subser = ser[starti:starti+2]
>>>     # print subseries, to see, what we are going to plot
>>>     print subser
>>>     # plot subseries as bar subchart
>>>     subser.plot(ax=axs[graphi], kind="bar")
a    10
b    12
dtype: int64
c     8
d    44
dtype: int64
e    34
f    18
dtype: int64
```

and make the plot to appear:

```
>>> plt.show()
```

[image: 3 subplots with barcharts]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want bar charts for slices of the data. From your question it isn't clear what slices you want, but here are some examples:

```
import pandas as pd

# Generate some fake data 
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['id_{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)], 
               'y':np.random.uniform(size=10)})
```

- Plot every other ID starting from 1 (so 1, 3, 5...)

  ```
  df[1::2].plot(kind='bar')
  ```
- Plot just two consecutive ID's

  ```
  df[0:2].plot(kind='bar')
  ```
- A variant on the last: plot the two consecutive ID's for all rows of data

  ```
  for i in range(0, len(df), 2):
      df[i:i+2].plot(kind='bar')
  ```

I know this isn't a complete answer, but I was trying to figure out what you wanted. I thought I would post it to see if it helps, but just leave a comment if I am well off topic and I will delete.